# Box div inside slider not aligning in responsive page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap3` for my page design.Here I am adding a banner(slider), inside that I am adding a box with some content. The code as follows

```
<div class="row">
  <section id="slider">

    <ul class="rslides" id="modest-slider">

      <li class="slider-wrapper">

        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=slider1" alt="slider1" />
        </div>

        <div class="slider-caption container">
          <div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: auto; bottom:100%; max-bottom: 126px; width:100%; max-width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);height:100%; max-height:130px;">
            <h1>Exclusively  New Concept!</h1>
            <p class="slider-description2">
              Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample...
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.slider-caption -->

      </li>
      <!-- /.slider-wrapper -->
      </ui>
  </section>
```

In browser full screen it is working perfectly. While when I am resizing my browser it got merging inside my header. How can I avoid this? How can make the box content visible in all sizes?

Please refer the images

[image: Full screen]
[image: Resized]

Help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Use [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for responsive and for images, you should `imv-responsive` class, too.

Comment: @Khay can you update it?? It will be helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about header bar, since you must be using your own custom CSS for that. According to your HTML provided, it should be fixed like below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <section id="slider">
            <ul class="rslides" id="modest-slider">
                <li class="slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="slider-img-container">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=slider1" alt="slider1" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider-caption container">
                        <div class="col-md-7" style="border-left-width: 4px; top: auto; bottom:100%; max-bottom: 126px; width:100%; max-width: 600px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);height:100%; max-height:130px;">
                            <h1>Exclusively  New Concept!</h1>
                            <p class="slider-description2">Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample Lorem ipsum sample...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.slider-caption -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.slider-wrapper -->
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>      
</div>
```